# About `std::conditional_variable`. Why this code snippet stall?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/ba3s7dE9v) stall?

The program intends to output `firstsecondthird` whereas the program stalls after `firstsecond` has been printed.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        
    }

    void first(std::function<void()> printFirst) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
                         
            cv1.wait(lk, [this](){return 1==state;});

            doing = 1;
            // printFirst() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFirst();
                
            state = 2;
        }

        cv2.notify_one();
    }

    void second(std::function<void()> printSecond) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
            if(state !=2 )
            {
                if((1 == state)&&(1 != doing))
                {
                    lk.unlock();
                    cv1.notify_one();
                }
            }
                        
            cv2.wait(lk, [this](){return 2==state;});

            doing = 2;
            // printSecond() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond();
            
            state = 3;
        }

        cv3.notify_one();
    }

    void third(std::function<void()> printThird) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
            if(state !=3 )
            {
                if((1 == state)&&(1 != doing))
                {
                    lk.unlock();
                    cv1.notify_one();
                }
                else if((2 == state)&&(2 != doing))
                {
                    lk.unlock();
                    cv2.notify_one();
                }
            }
                        
            cv3.wait(lk, [this](){return 3==state;});

            // printThird() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
            printThird();
            
            state = 3;
        }
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cv1;
    std::condition_variable cv2;
    std::condition_variable cv3;
    std::mutex mutex;
    int state{1};
    int doing{0};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.second([]()->void{std::cout <<"second" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.first([]()->void{std::cout <<"first" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.third([]()->void{std::cout <<"third" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    for(auto itr=threads.begin(); itr!=threads.end(); itr++)
    {
        itr->join();
    }
}
```

Comment: This program exhibits undefined behavior. It calls `cv2.wait(lk, ...)` while `lk` hasn't in fact locked the mutex (thanks to the earlier `lk.unlock();`)

Comment: In any case, the part of `second` that calls `cv1.notify_one()` is unnecessary. So is the part of `third` that calls `cv1.notify_one()` and `cv2.notify_one()`. Just drop everything there between `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);` and `cvX.wait`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry, I can't get your idea. Could you please explain that in more detail for me? Maybe a simple example is more clear.

Comment: Which part is unclear? `cv2.wait(lk, ...)` requires that `lk` actually hold the mutex. But you've just called `lk.unlock()` so `lk` does not in fact hold the mutex. Thus violating the preconditions of the library function.

Comment: Taking another step back, it's unclear why you even need threads for this, when they do the work sequentially anyway.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik >>*In any case, the part of second that calls `cv1.notify_one()` is unnecessary.* 
I understand this point, thank you.
>> *"Taking another step back, it's unclear why you even need threads for this" *  It's a question on LeetCode(question id:1114).
>> cv2.wait(lk, ...) requires that lk actually hold the mutex. 
I think the `lk` would be locked in the implementation of `cv2.wait()`.Any reference for me to dig deeper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoted from the comments of @Igor Tandetnik.

As per the [document](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/wait/#:%7E:text=std%3A%3A%20condition_variable%20%3A%3Await%20Wait%20until%20notified%20The%20execution,lck.unlock%20%28%29%2C%20allowing%20other%20locked%20threads%20to%20continue.), which says that

> template  void wait (unique_lock& lck, Predicate pred);
>
> lck
>
> A unique_lock object whose mutex object is currently locked by
> this thread. All concurrent calls to wait member functions of this
> object shall use the same underlying mutex object (as returned by
> lck.mutex()).

So, `cv2.wait(lk, ...)` requires that lk actually hold the `mutex`.

And if `lk.unlock();` is removed, this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/67G61czzo) could work as expected.

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        
    }

    void first(std::function<void()> printFirst) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
                         
            cv1.wait(lk, [this](){return 1==state;});

            doing = 1;
            // printFirst() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFirst();
                
            state = 2;
        }

        cv2.notify_one();
    }

    void second(std::function<void()> printSecond) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
            if(state !=2 )
            {
                if((1 == state)&&(1 != doing))
                {
                    //lk.unlock();  //removed
                    cv1.notify_one();
                }
            }
                        
            cv2.wait(lk, [this](){return 2==state;});

            doing = 2;
            // printSecond() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond();
            
            state = 3;
        }

        cv3.notify_one();
    }

    void third(std::function<void()> printThird) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
            if(state !=3 )
            {
                if((1 == state)&&(1 != doing))
                {
                    //lk.unlock();  //removed
                    cv1.notify_one();
                }
                else if((2 == state)&&(2 != doing))
                {
                    //lk.unlock();  //removed
                    cv2.notify_one();
                }
            }
                        
            cv3.wait(lk, [this](){return 3==state;});

            // printThird() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
            printThird();
            
            state = 3;
        }
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cv1;
    std::condition_variable cv2;
    std::condition_variable cv3;
    std::mutex mutex;
    int state{1};
    int doing{0};
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.second([]()->void{std::cout <<"second" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.first([]()->void{std::cout <<"first" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.third([]()->void{std::cout <<"third" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    for(auto itr=threads.begin(); itr!=threads.end(); itr++)
    {
        itr->join();
    }
}
```

And the code snippet could be improved as this one:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
   
// @lc code=start
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {
        
    }

    void first(std::function<void()> printFirst) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);

            // printFirst() outputs "first". Do not change or remove this line.
            printFirst();
                
            state = 2;
        }

        cv2.notify_one();
    }

    void second(std::function<void()> printSecond) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
                 
            cv2.wait(lk, [this](){return 2==state;});

            // printSecond() outputs "second". Do not change or remove this line.
            printSecond();
            
            state = 3;
        }

        cv3.notify_one();
    }

    void third(std::function<void()> printThird) 
    {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(mutex);
                        
            cv3.wait(lk, [this](){return 3==state;});

            // printThird() outputs "third". Do not change or remove this line.
            printThird();
            
            state = 3;
        }
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable cv2;
    std::condition_variable cv3;
    std::mutex mutex;
    int state{1};
};
// @lc code=end

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.second([]()->void{std::cout <<"second" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.first([]()->void{std::cout <<"first" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(300));
    threads.push_back(std::thread([&](){foo.third([]()->void{std::cout <<"third" <<std::endl;});}));

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));

    for(auto itr=threads.begin(); itr!=threads.end(); itr++)
    {
        itr->join();
    }
}
```